# Why am I getting this Scanner error?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm using 2 scanners to read a file. One grabs the first and second line (since I need them for something else) with a

```
int a = fileScanner.nextInt();
fileScanner.nextLine();
int b = fileScanner.nextInt();
fileScanner.nextLine();
```

I then grab the rest of the file, line by line, and send a line to a different class.

```
    while( fileScanner.hasNextLine() ){
        line = fileScanner.nextLine();
        NameRecord current = new NameRecord (line, startYear, decades);
        names.add(current);
    }
```

(Ignore the rest of the code.)
I then take the first Word of the line, then the rest is numbers I need to store in an array so I use this:

```
Scanner lineSc = new Scanner(line);
    dataName = lineSc.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < decades; i++) {
        yearData[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineSc.next());
    }
    lineSc.close();
```

But in the end, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at NameRecord.<init>(NameRecord.java:36)
at Names.<init>(Names.java:34)
at NameSurfer.simpleTest(NameSurfer.java:176)
at NameSurfer.main(NameSurfer.java:202)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems you are calling next for your lineSc scanner even when it does not have elements any more. You should always check with hasNext ==> for (int i = 0; i < decades && lineSc.hasNext(); i++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the line

```
yearData[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineSc.next());
```

you actually call `next()` after the `next()` was already called in the line `dataName = lineSc.next();`
So at the end of the file you try to read one extra piece of the data when there is no more data actually.

The `decades` variable' value is greater than the actual length of the line you try to read while it has to be of length `lineSc.length()-1` or less.

Comment: Yeah, because the first one (dataName = lineSc.next();) takes the first String of the line, then the rest is the same amount of integers as the number of decades.

Comment: Well then your decades variable' value is greater than the actual length of the line you try to read while it has to be of length lineSc.length()-1 or less.